# Mac : Run Foundation Tool app as cronjob?

Tags: xcode, macos, cron

This may not be completely programming related ...

In Xcode I wrote a little Foundation Tool application for maintenance. Copy files from A to B , delete logs and so on. Now I want to run the application in background once a day or once an hour.
How do I set this up?

Can it be done with a Foundation Tool application or is there another Xcode project type for tasks like this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "Foundation Tool application" is a command-line application, then you should be able to run it from cron just fine.

Another way to run it (if you want to be consistent with the OS X built-in daily maintenance scripts) would be to run it from a script in /etc/periodic/daily (look at the existing scripts there for examples)

Comment: My Foundation Tool is indeed a command-line application. Thanks.